# 'XXXX()' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context

Tags: c#

Given this code:

```
public enum Stuff
{   
    a,b,c
}

public class RuleManager
{
    public Stuff Stuff()
    {
        return Stuff.a;
    }

    public int BizRule()
    {
        Stuff currStuff = Stuff();
        return 1; //who cares, just proving a point
    }
}
```

I have an error on the `public Stuff Stuff()` return statement. Saying that `Stuff()` is a `method` which is not valid in the given context. I understand that its since the method and the enum share the same token, but I want to know why the compiler can't discern the difference and how I could make it do so.

Ok to further clarify, I have this code from an existing project that compiles just fine, but when placed into a new one the compiler has this issue.

Why would it compile fine in one class library project but not another?

Comment: why would you name a method the same name as your enum.. ?

Comment: this is code within a framework that I did NOT design, but am having to work with. I agree its not ideal, but theres 10's of thousands of lines of stuff like this. Trying to work with it.

Comment: _I want to know why the compiler can't discern the difference and how I could make it do so_: Because the language doesn't permit it; write your own language spec and compiler (or at least a non-conforming compiler for this language)?

Comment: @Matt this should have been quite obvious even the compiler complains when pasting  your code in directly.. I would definitely not use the following when creating methods `Reserved Names` and I would make my method names more meaningful please read up on Methods and enums to get the general idea of my initial comment

Comment: I can't believe that there are 10's of thousands of lines that are incorrect in your code.. if it compiles in one and not the other there can be several reasons.. does the other one not utilize namespace where the new one does..? does the old one use nested classes where the new one doesn't ???

Comment: C# will determine whether you're referring to a type or member of the same name if the member is a property or field, but it won't do it if the member is a method. If it's a method, C# will assume you're referring to the method and you'll get this error. I'm this is desscribed somewhere in the standard, but I don't really have time to look at the moment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I want to know why the compiler can't discern the difference

Because of C# Specification chapter 7.4 Member lookup:

> A member lookup is the process whereby the meaning of a name in the context of a type is determined.

This process follows a set of rules which ultimately search from the closest scope on outward, where the method `RuleManager.Stuff()` is found first and searching is then stopped. Because you can't invoke a method without parentheses, it's invalid and the given error is shown.

An easy fix would be to introduce a namespace:

```
namespace EnumNamespace
{
    public enum Stuff
    {
        a, b, c
    }
}

public class RuleManager
{
    public EnumNamespace.Stuff Stuff()
    {
        return EnumNamespace.Stuff.a;
    }

    public int BizRule()
    {
        EnumNamespace.Stuff currStuff = Stuff();
        return 1; //who cares, just proving a point
    }
}
```

I can't quite see how your code would compile. Try to create an example that reproduces that problem (*"Why does this invalid C# code compile?"*).

Comment: If you don't have a namespace, `public global::Stuff Stuff()` should work.

Comment: Good call you guys. Scoping all the enums with a namespace (which is doable considering the depth of code) resolved the compile issues on my end. Thanks!